# Arbitrary content for right side of markdown badge

Tags: markdown, badge, arbitrary-values

So we've got an *internal use-case* where we want to create a markdown badge that serves an arbitrary string from a service here internally. Basically we want the left side of the badge to say `version` with the right side being the content that comes out of querying a service/link. The service internally is Artifactory and we just want to get the latest version of a given Artifact to serve on a project page.

I'm searching all around and trying different things but coming up empty handed. Anyone have any suggestions one way or another?

EDIT: I understand there is the "endpoint badge" but it expects content to be returned in json format. This endpoint quite literally return a version in string format (i.e. plain/text).

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: There's the [static badge](https://shields.io/badges) - if you could figure out a way to make a HTTP request, and substitute that value into the URL, that could work. Shields.io is also open source, so you could fork it, modify the endpoint badge to support plain text, and host your own copy. That might be quite a bit of work for the gain, though.

Comment: @NickODell yup and that's exactly what we did. Ended up creating our own _shields service_ for this purpose. Wasn't too bad actually and just opened the door for more possibilities on this front.